# CodeIgniter 2 error when connecting to new server. Call to a member function num_rows()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I built a site on my personal webserver. Everything worked fine. When I put it online, imported and connected the database I go some strange error to a core file

Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in ****/system/database/DB_active_rec.php on line 986

I have tested and confirmed that the database is connecting. So this must be a server configuration issue. But can anyone suggest to me what it is?

The issue began as a database connection problem that I fixed by changing db_debug to false

Part of me thinks it's a memory issue on the new webserver.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '***';
$db['default']['password'] = '***';
$db['default']['database'] = '***';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: paste the code where error occurs that might be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

This could be a number of things. It looks like your script is expecting a value returned from the database row and is not getting any.  What is on you line 986 ? Is it Github? Does your new database accept null in the fields it relates to ?

Comment: This is what is on like 986 
`if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
  {
   return 0;
  }
`
Not on github and It's the same database from the development server. It must be some kind of server difference.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add **`result()`** to the end of your query inside your model. A typical model function should be like this:

```
$q=$this->db->get('table_name')->result();
return $q;
```

Your model function should return an array() if you're using it in a `foreach` look inside your controller.

Comment: But why would it work perfectly on one server and then differently on the next. The code shouldn't be what causes it to break, should it?

Comment: My guess is your local database is not same as your server database. Would you confirm that all data is the same? I think your controller is receiving an empty variable instead of an empty array so that might be the problem.

Comment: I can confirm that the DB is the same. I exported it and then imported it. Nothing changed and there were no errors.

Comment: Comment some of your codes which plays with data and try to find  correct line of code which causes problem. And Add `profiler` to your controllers. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (for the second time, so I feel I should dig up this subject, might help someone), check :

- if you did not forget to import a table on your distant server
- if you spelled any table name wrong (eg - instead of _)

Answer (score 0):

also you can check your table_name (upper/lower case). For me that helps.